# Weird behaviour with React Hooks and FileReader

Tags: html, reactjs, filereader, react-hooks

I'm new to React Hooks and honestly I'm not sure if this problem is related to Hooks or if I'm just doing something generally wrong.

I want to build a image uploader comonent that uses the HTML5 `FileReader` in order to show users the uploaded images before actually POSTing them.
Below is what I have so far.

Basically `<div id="from-effect"></div>` is currently my way of checking whether the images could be rendered.
I first wanted to fill this `<div>` without side effects (like `<div>I have {files.length} files</div>`) but this didn't react to changes at all.
The solution below with `useEffect` is reacting to changes.
However, if you try uploading a few images you will notice that quite often it's showing wrong results.

```
function FileUploader(props) {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const loadImageContent = (name, newFiles) => {
    return (e) => {
      newFiles.push({ name: name, src: e.target.result });
    };
  }

  const handleUpload = async (e) => {
    const newFiles = [];
    for (const file of e.target.files) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = loadImageContent(file.name, newFiles);
      await reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    setFiles(newFiles);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('in use Effect, files:', files);
    const prevCont = document.getElementById("from-effect");
    prevCont.innerHTML = `I have ${files.length} files`;
  });

  return <div>
    <input
      type="file" name="fileUploader" id="fileUploader"
      accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"
      onChange={handleUpload}
    />
    <div id="from-effect"></div>
  </div>;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Or even better, how can I implement this without side effects?

Comment: Remember to include `useEffect` dependencies: when should use effect run again. In your case I guess `files`: `useEffect(() => {/*...*/}, [files]);`

Comment: Could you elaborate more the statement *"showing the wrong results"*? what is the actual output and your expected output.

Comment: @JosephD. when I upload 2 files, it should show "I have 2 files", but sometimes it shows a different number (e.g. "I have 0 files").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I follow your ultimate goal, or what you mean when you say you want to show users the uploaded images before POSTing them - do you want to POST automatically, or do you want the user to click an "upload/save/POST" button or something?

Here is an example of how to display images:

***Edit:*** *made things a little more clear, added "save" button which shows an alert that contains data you could possibly use to `POST` back to your server. Also, added a method to "JSONify" the file metadata, since the way we are uploading files does not let us natively convert `[object File]` into JSON.*

```js
const { useState } = React;

function FileUploader(props) {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  
  const getFileMetadata = file => {
    /**
     * The way we are handling uploads does not allow us to
     * turn the uploaded [object File] into JSON.
     *
     * Therefore, we have to write our own "toJSON()" method.
     */
    return {
      lastModified: file.lastModified,
      name: file.name,
      size: file.size,
      type: file.type,
      webkitRelativePath: file.webkitRelativePath
    }
  }

  const handleUpload = e => {
    let newstate = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
      let file = e.target.files[i];
      let metadata = getFileMetadata(file);
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      newstate = [...newstate, { url, metadata }];
    }
    setFiles(newstate);
  };
  
  const handleSave = () => {
    alert(`POST Files Here..\n\n ${JSON.stringify(files,null,2)}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple onChange={handleUpload} />
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleSave} disabled={!(files && files.length > 0)}>
          Save Image(s)
        </button>
      </div>
      {files.map(f => {
        return (
          <div>
            <img src={f.url} height="100" width="100" />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<FileUploader />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes, I want to have another button for the actual POST. Thanks, didnt know of `URL.createObjectURL` yet. Will try out in a few hours when I get home

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: works, that's almost what I wanted. just `[...newstate]` instead of `[...files, ...newstate]`.

Comment: @mRcSchwering sorry about that, I didn't know if you wanted to append images to what the user already uploaded.  I have also updated this answer to show how you can get the file metadata during upload.  I have also added a makeshift save button which allows you to see the data (via an alert) you could potentially POST back to your server. Cheers!